# Devise Add Second Set of Nested Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I'm running a Rails 4 app with Devise 3 and I want to set up a secondary set of routes for Devise. I have a `Portal` model, which represents a sub-site that is unique, but shares the same core user base. I want to be able to send a user to a route like `/portals/:portal_id/users/sign_in` and have it behave the same way as the default `/users/sign_in` route that Devise creates using `devise_for :users`. How can I do this?

Here are my routes:

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}
    root 'general#home'

    resources :portals, controller: 'portals/general' do
        member do
            root 'portals/general#home'
        end
    end
end
```

I also have a `RegistrationsController` that overrides the default Devise controller like so:

```
class Portals::RegistrationsController < RegistrationsController
    layout 'portals/layouts/application'

    def create
        @portal = Portal.friendly.find(params[:id])
        build_resource(sign_up_params)

        resource_saved = resource.save
        yield resource if block_given?
        if resource_saved
            if resource.active_for_authentication?
                set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
                sign_up(resource_name, resource)
                redirect_to :back
            else
                set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
                expire_data_after_sign_in!
                respond_with resource, location: after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
            end
        else
            clean_up_passwords resource
            # respond_with(resource, location: root_path)
            flash[:notice] = resource.errors.full_messages.first
            redirect_to root_portal_path(resource)
        end
    end
end
```